# SQL Server 2008R2 Express upgrade to SQL Server 2012 Express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I currently have SQL Server 2008 R2 Express installed.
I like to upgrade to SQL Server 2012 Express.

I am using a 64 bit system (Windows 7 Home Premium).

Is there a wizard that can do the upgrade? I checked a few places on the web but was not sure which option to choose.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143393%28v=sql.110%29.aspx), upgrade is supported from SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 Express to SQL Server 2012 Express. Install the [2008 R2 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26727), and run installation of 2012 Express normally. It should pick up and offer an upgrade. Your operating system is also [supported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506%28v=sql.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. Which option do I pick when I go to 2008 R2 SP1

Answer (score 1):

The SQL Server Installation Center (when you download the Express 2012 64) it give you an option to upgrade the SQL server 2005, 2008, 2008 R2 too) , it helps to fix issues when you backup and restore between servers, I also used "Windows Update" to update the existing MS-SQL-Express

[image]