# Run python script when SQL 2008 DB Column changes

Tags: python, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Say I have a SQL 2008 Database, which contains the inventory data for my business. I need to trigger a python script, once an item qty is changed. This can result under several conditions, it could be a sale order, or simply a qty change. The python script will transform the data, and upload it to google sheets.

I need this to trigger in realtime, like when the specified columns change or records are created, I need to fire off the script.

Its preferred the solution runs on the DB server itself, without having to pay for other integration tools such as Zapier. (Besides Zapier wont help here)

Constraints:
I cannot move the database to the cloud (Business Restriction)
Upgrading the database to a new version is not possible either (budget)
Changing the Database to open source is not possible either (other application dependencies)

Its a real pickle, but I'm trying to find a solution for a real time trigger.
Failing that I could almost implement a periodic scanning method, but this will create new problems.

Havent tried anything yet, because I have no idea what to try here.
Some google searches, but was not able to find a solution.

Comment: This is something you should be doing in your application layer. When the application `INSERT`s or `UPDATEs` (or `DELETE`s?) a row, then it should also do this other task. In this case, it seems, uploading data to a Google Sheet.

Comment: Side note, SQL Server 2008 has been completely unsupported since 2019; it is *long* past time you got your upgrade path finalised and implemented.

Comment: @Larnu the company will not upgrade, not my decision. They will move to a new system in 2024, this is just a temp. measure until then. Also cannot do it in the application layer, because its a compiled binary, nothing to change there, its a legacy system.

Comment: Maybe get your company to upgrade then. Though I recommend *against* it (as it'll kill performance) you can run Python scripts in much more recent (and supported) versions of SQL Server using `sp_execute_external_script`. I would suggest a "better" solution would be to have a Python task execute on a regular basis, and update the Google Sheet; don't have it "triggered" as (again) such logic would be somethign for the application layer.

Comment: You can create a SQL Server Agent job that runs inside your trigger and runs python or whatever. To start a job, one runs: exec msdb..sp_start_job 'your jobname'. This will also avoid problems of xp_cmdshell rights and concurrent starting of python scripts as well. Just make sure to test so the trigger doesn't crash if job is already running. It's not real time real time, but real enough.

Answer (score 0):

Source: https://www.sqlshack.com/use-xp-cmdshell-extended-procedure/

The answer to this is to configure the required trigger, using xp_cmdshell. You can then use xp_cmdshell to run a .bat or .py file.

Be aware of the permissions xp_cmdshell is running as, most likely this will be the SQL user that runs the file, you will have to ensure this user has the right privileges at the OS level to execute files, and write to any directories that need to be written to.

If anyone is in a similar situation, they could look into upgrading to SQL Express (which is free), not sure if this would break the application, but there is a good chance it will not([SQL Server 2008R2 Express upgrade to SQL Server 2012 Express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17820936/sql-server-2008r2-express-upgrade-to-sql-server-2012-express)).

It goes without saying this is certainly not best practice, and if you can at all avoid it, it would be best to run a scheduled task instead.